# Close as exact duplicate doesn't work on mobile Safari

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I cannot start closing question as duplicate from mobile Safari (tested on both iPhone and iPad). When I choose close as exact duplicate and paste url of the question the dialog freezes. The text is blured - both url and former text is visible and question's preview doesn't load which causes that vote to close button is still disabled.

Comment: +1. It *sometimes* works. Far as I can tell, one of the issues is with tabbing out of the text box - not something you can really do on that form on an iPhone. I've also seen it fail when someone already proposed a duplicate. The "Vote to close" button never became enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does in fact work, so long as you register a "keypress" in the close input box.

That is, if you paste, that's not a keypress.

So enter a space at the end of the URL after pasting (this won't harm anything) and everything should work as you expect.

I was indeed able to close this question as a proof of concept on my iPhone.