# Can't vote to close from the mobile site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web

The (fairly) new mobile layout is great and very functional. However, it seems there's no "close" link next to "edit" and "flag" when viewing a question. The flagging interface works just fine in the mobile site, so I would think the vote-to-close interface could be easily done as well. However it's simply not there. Is this by design or just in the works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it was possible to vote to close before, via the flag link, we've recently deployed an actual "close" link on the mobile theme.

We *may* have to go back on this in the future.  We're absurdly cramped for space already, and if we absolutely need it in that menu, "close" will be first on the chopping block.

For now though, it's available.

Comment: I really don't see it as being cramped for space — the edit/close/flag links together take up only about 30% of the width of the page. Plus, if it wrapped onto two lines, I honestly don't think anyone would be complaining :)

Comment: @Kevin, I'm not sure this is [working correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102907/152009)?

Comment: *Thank you very much* for adding this! There's been enough room on every device I've seen, and I use this pretty often--at least when browsing SO.

Answer (score 6):

I could have sworn that this came up recently, but I'm unable to find the post. Assuming my memory isn't playing tricks on me, I seem to recall a developer mentioning that the mobile interface was optimized for the most common use cases, which may or may not include voting to close questions.

In either case, the "it does not belong here" flag option will load the exact same dialog as you'd get from the normal close link, so if you're intent on voting to close from the mobile theme you can still currently do so:

[image: close response on mobile site]

Comment: That's true. Does choosing one of those options (on which the formatting is ugly—that's a different topic) actually do a vote-to-close, or a flag?

Comment: It's a true vote-to-close. I think I actually voted to close something from my iPhone the other day, and got the typical "4 more votes..." message in response.

Comment: Good to know. Still, not the most intuitive way to do close votes (plus, I think the "doesn't belong here" flag option does the same thing on the full site?)

Comment: I only see [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92967/close-as-exact-duplicate-doesnt-work-on-mobile-safari) @Tim, which may or may not be related -- depending on the mobile OS of the OP.

Comment: @jtbandes Right, and I'm unsure on whether it's intentionally not made more obvious, or if it just hasn't been done yet (though for some reason I feel like it's the former). And yeah, that option works the same way on the full site.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I am using iOS and mobile Safari, but that one sounds like a bug report for the full (not mobile) site.

Comment: Yep.  It was also posted *well before* the mobile site was released.

Comment: @Tim: I think you're thinking of the comment exchange [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101227/on-iphone-4-off-topic-icons-are-a-skewed) between myself and Kevin Montrose. This is where I first figured out that flags == vote to close on the mobile site. I don't really buy Kevin's argument... there's plenty of room for a "close" link on every mobile device that I've seen. But whatever.

Comment: @Cody Ah, that seems likely, thanks. I can see arguments for and against having the close link, so I don't feel too strongly about it one way or the other.