# Mobile close votes shown incorrectly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, mobile-web

I just saw the close link while browsing on my blackberry.  It came in handy with [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102897/what-is-the-problem-with-the-faq).  However, after voting to close, the mobile browser incorrectly rendered.  Instead of `edit close(2) flag`, I saw:

> edit (2)-link" id="mobile-close-post-102897" title="vote to close or reopen question; when > closed, no new answers can be added">close (2)flag

Perhaps a rogue narwahl was munching on the opening `<`?

**Note:** [This feature was just recently added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102389/cant-vote-to-close-from-the-mobile-site/102859#102859).

Comment: Yep, I also saw this from an iPhone several hours ago.

Comment: What?! You mean there's a "close" link in the mobile theme now??!

Comment: @Cody, Yep!  Just added I think.

Comment: Just saw this now on my android...can't seem to get rid of it but glad it is fixed (and presume it'll sort itself shortly or with enough cache clearing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Woops.

This will be fixed with the next deploy.